# How to apply multiple actions to the same active region (using CUA-mode)

Tags: region, mark

Imagine one wants to apply two functions (A and B, where A could be commenting the code with `M-;` and B convert the text to all-caps with `C-x C-u`) to the same active region. I would proceed as follows:

1. set the mark with `C-<SPC>`
2. move the cursor until the end of the region I want to modify
3. run function A
4. repeat 1. and 2.
5. run function B

How should I proceed to run both A and B (and potentially others) without repeating the selection step? It seems this behavior arises since most functions which work on an active region implicitly call `deactivate-mark` on completion.

---

The question above highlights one of the use cases described [in this other post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12952/what-is-the-usefulness-of-exchange-point-and-mark).

Comment: While the answer to the other question duplicate the answer here, the questions are very different. If I was searching for the answer to 'how to apply multiple actions to the region', how would I know to search for 'what is the use of exchange mark and point'?

Comment: @Tyler: Completely agree, but cannot reopen the question by myself. I myself only found the other question after reading the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At step 4, do `C-x C-x` (`exchange-point-and-mark`) which will reactivate the mark as it swaps point and mark (and so takes point back to where you started in Step 1).

Comment: Thank you. I had dismissed this option because it seemed not to work, but upon further inspection I realized it was being overridden by ```cua-mode```. One either deactivates ```cua-mode```, or else uses the following: 

```(require 'cua-base)
(progn
  (define-key cua-global-keymap (kbd "C-x C-x") 'exchange-dot-and-mark)
  )
```

where ```exchange-dot-and-mark``` is an alias for ```exchange-point-and-mark```, but has no predefined keybind.